# Invalid column name when using sp_executesql 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When I try to execute a dynamic query inside a stored procedure I'm getting an error.

My code is:

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @AllowanceBadge nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @AllowFieldName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Amount Decimal
SET @AllowanceBadge  ='SIP0980'
SET @AllowFieldName ='xxxxx'
SET @Amount = 100

SET @Query = 'UPDATE tbl_PayrollTransaction SET '+ @AllowFieldName +' = '+convert(varchar,@Amount) + 'WHERE BadgeNumber = '+@AllowanceBadge
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```

I'm getting following error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'SIP0980'.

Tell me where I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need quotes around the SIP0890

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @AllowanceBadge nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @AllowFieldName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Amount Decimal
SET @AllowanceBadge  ='SIP0980'
SET @AllowFieldName ='xxxxx'
SET @Amount = 100

SET @Query = 'UPDATE tbl_PayrollTransaction SET '+ @AllowFieldName +' = '+convert(varchar,@Amount) + 'WHERE BadgeNumber = '''+@AllowanceBadge+''''
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```